# @XmlAttribute appears as @XmlElement in xml response

Tags: java, intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I have an application that receive http rest request and I've to response with xml.

So i declared an xsd:

"Root Element"

```
<xs:element name="root">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="test" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:attribute name="test2" type="xs:duration"/>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         ...
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I use jaxb to generate my java class (and id appears as Xmlattribute)

BUT, when I test my application with SoapUI, the reponse is:

```
<root>
   <test/>
   <id>toto</id>      <----------
</root>
```

Why my attribute appears as an element.

Comment: Please post your generated class.

Comment: My generated class "lexicore":

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "test"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root{

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://.../.../xml")
    protected Test test;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

(getter/setter)
...
}

Answer (score 0):

My generated class "lexicore":

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "test"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root{

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://.../.../xml")
    protected Test test;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

(getter/setter)
...
}
```

Comment: Add this as part of the Question. I tried marshaling your generated Java clas and it seems to produce the correct output.

Comment: Yes marshal serialization produce the correct output.
I think i found my error --> bad project configuration for spring-boot. Sorry
Before i had the same class for "SpringBootApplication" and "Controller", I changed that with main class in the racine of project, and controller class for request mapping